# jquery add html from another html file doesn't work

Tags: jquery, html

I'm quite new to jquery and I looked up the .load() here:
http://api.jquery.com/load/
and tried one of their examples, however when I tried it locally I don't get it to work

HTML file

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Test</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<b>Projects:</b>
<ol id="new-projects"></ol>

<script>
    $( "#new-projects" ).load( "laf15/resources/load.html #projects li" );
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

load.html

```
<li>one</li>
<li>two</li>
<li>three</li>
<li>four</li>
```

not quite sure what I've done wrong, so any help would be great!

Comment: Where is the HTML file located?  It's possible you just need to change the path to `/laf15/resources/load.html #projects li`.  Is the javascript console reporting any errors?

Comment: You are using a way too old JQuery version. Maybe that is the problem? And as @JosephMarikle asked, are you having any errors being reported in console?

Comment: How do I find this mythical java-script console? I haven't done web dev in 2 years and it's not my forte

Answer (score 0):

The URL you are loading is not a valid URL.
The space character needs to be encoded.
I think you probably added more chars than you should.
Try to write just:

```
$( "#new-projects" ).load( "laf15/resources/load.html" );
```

if the URL is correct your script is going to work.
By writing this URL you are loading the file "load.html" inside the folder "resources" that is contained in the "laf15" folder.
So the file you wrote needs to be in the folder that contains "laf15" folder.
Your folder tree should look like this:

```
    -mainfolder
        -yourfile.html
        -laf15
            -resources
                -load.html
```

Comment: This is not correct.  jQuery's [`.load() method`](http://api.jquery.com/load/#loading-page-fragments) will parse that part of the url and interpret it as a fragment.  It is not a valid URL, but it is valid syntax in this particular case.

Comment: It is already structured as such, with load.html in 
C:\Users\username\page\laf15\resources\load.html
and test.html in
C:\Users\username\page\test.html